# User login status activation check in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm new in Codeigniter. I have a login system where user with status is 0 can't do login yet and where user with status 1 can login. I might be have a mistake in my code. So, i hope you can find where is my mistake and help me to make it right. here's my code.

My Controller

```
public function login() {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('no', 'No', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[16]|integer');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|md5|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');

            if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE) {
                $this->load->view('v_login');
            }else{
                    $no = $this->input->post('no');
                    $password = $this->input->post('password');
                    $cek = $this->m_user->ambilPengguna($no, $password);
                    $status = $this->m_user->ambilStatus($no); //HERE'S THE PROBLEM
                    if($cek->num_rows()<> 0 && $status == '1') { //HERE'S TOO, IT WON'T CHECK THE STATUS.
                            $this->session->set_userdata('isLogin', TRUE);
                            $this->session->set_userdata('data_user',$cek->row());
                            redirect('c_belajar');
                    }else {
                        echo " <script>
                                    alert('Login failed! call the administrator to activate your account');
                                    history.go(-1);
                        </script>";        
                }
            }  
        }
```

My Model

```
public function ambilPengguna($no, $password) {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('tb_user');
                $this->db->where('no_id', $no);
                $this->db->where('password', $password);


                $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query;
        }

        public function ambilStatus($no){
            $this->db->select('status');
            $this->db->from('tb_user');
            $this->db->where('no_id', $no);
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query;
        }
```

There's a mistake on controller. Please help me.

Comment: Instead of checking for status in a separate query , you could have done it in the same one.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm newbie. Could you tell me how? @Malik Mudassar

Answer (score 0):

Alright! May I suggest a little code restructure

**Controller**

```
class YourController extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}

public function login()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        $config=array(
            array(
                'field' => 'no',
                'label' => 'Number',
                'rules' => 'trim|required',
            ),
            array(
                'field' => 'password',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'rules' => 'trim|required',
            )
        );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
        if($this->form_validation->run()==false)
        {
            $data['errors']=validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            $check=$this->login_model->checkUser($_POST); // you can use xss clean here filter post data
            if(!$check)
            {
                $data['errors']='Invalid Password';
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }
            elseif($check==1)
            {
                $data['errors']='Your account status is not active yet, Please contact Administrator';
                $this->load->view('login',$data);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_uerdata($check);
                redirect(base_url().'dashboard');
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
 }
}
```

**Model**

```
class login_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function checkUser($data)
{
    $st=$this->db->select('*')
        ->from('tbl_user')
        ->Where('no_id', $data['no'])
        ->where('password', $data['password'])
        ->get()->result_array();// you can use row()
    if(count($st)>0)
    {
        if($st[0]['status']==0){
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return $st[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I follow your code then its end up like this Fatal error: Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_driver as array in m_user.php line 56. in my code.. Line 56 is if($st[0]['status']==0).

Comment: in your config->database.php change the driver to mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this working in my project..

Your Model

```
    public function ambilStatus(){

        $this->db->where('no_id', $this->input->post('your input name'));
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'tb_user');
        $ret = $query->row();
        return $ret->account_status;

    }
```

And Your Controller

```
        $status = $this->m_user->ambilStatus();
        if($status && $cek->num_rows() == 1 ) {
```